# How to prevent android studio from putting files in a SVN change list?

Tags: android-studio, svn, version-control

How to prevent android studio from putting files in a SVN change list? Even better, do not do anything with version control.

Comment: You should add more details in your question. Please show an example. A screenshot would be helpful, too.